# Turn on xtrace with environment variable

Tags: bash, environment-variables, trace

Bash has a sometimes-useful feature whereby if you turn on the "`-x`" option (I believe the symbolic name is `xtrace`), Bash outputs each line of script as it executes it.

I know of two ways to enable this behavior:

- In the script itself, say `set -x`
- On the command line, pass the `-x` option to Bash.

Is there any way of turning this option on via environment variables?

(In particular, I'm not invoking Bash myself, so I can't pass any options to it, and the script of interest is inside a compressed archive which I don't really feel like rebuilding. If I could set an environment variable, it would presumably be inherited by all child processes...)

- The manpage says something about `BASHOPTS`, but when I try it Bash says that's read-only. (Thanks for not mentioning that in the manpage.)
- Similarly, `SHELLOPTS` also seems to be read-only.
- You can select *which FD* is used with `BASH_XTRACEFD`. But I still need to turn tracing on in the first place.

Comment: Can you simply set `set -x` in the terminal and run the script?

Comment: Something like: `set -x; ./script.sh ; set +x`

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk The trace setting is not inherited by child processes.  If it (and other shell settings) was, it would make writing scripts _really_ tricky, as you would have to either reset options in every script, or write alternative code paths for each eventuality.

Comment: @Kusalananda: The example I posted works for me and if I understand correctly `./script.sh` is a child process, right?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk In `bash` 5.0.7, it would trace the call to the shell script, but tracing would _not_ be turned on inside the script itself, i.e. the shell option would not be inherited by the script.

Comment: @Kusalananda: ok, I got. Thanks for explanation.

Comment: If the script is inside a compressed archive, how are you running the script?

Comment: @Kusalananda It's actually a script that gets executed when an RPM is installed. I'd rather not have to rebuild the RPM to debug why it isn't working.

Comment: Um... You would _have_ to rebuild the RPM once you've fixed it, so you might as well unpack it and and fix it properly from the start. You are likely to want to iterate over this process until the issue is solved.  This is assuming that you are the maintainer of this RPM package.  If you aren't, you could file a bug report to the maintainer.

Comment: @Kusalananda If we run the script directly, it works perfectly. But if we install the RPM, something goes wrong somewhere.

Comment: So make a test RPM with the script and use `set -x` in it for testing. Also, you may want to ask a new question about rolling that RPM (with exactly what goes wrong and how it goes wrong). This seems to be your actual issue.

Answer (score 19):

Use `env` to ignore the `readonly` flags.

```
env SHELLOPTS=xtrace ./yourscript
```

Alternately, if you have `set -x` in your parent shell, you can `export SHELLOPTS` to cause it to be copied into the environment, and thus to the child (thanks to [Joe Casadonte](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/15785/joe-casadonte) for this):

```
set -x           # set xtrace flag
export SHELLOPTS # copy all options, including xtrace flag, to environment
./yourscript
```

Comment: In my case I could not invoke the script this way, I had to add it to a script being spawned via Java. To do that I added the following to the script: `env SHELLOPTS=xtrace; export SHELLOPTS; set -x`

Comment: @JoeCasadonte, that doesn't make sense: `env SHELLOPTS=xtrace; ...` doesn't set `SHELLOPTS` for any subsequent command in POSIX-compliant shells. (`env` is an external executable, `/usr/bin/env`, not a built-in shell feature; as such, it's not capable of modifying the shell's state; whereas `env var=val cmd ...` tells `env` to first set `var=val` in _its own_ environment and then use `execve()` to replace itself with `cmd`).

Comment: I had a running Java process (that I could not stop/restart) invoking a shell script, and I needed to  turn on `xtrace` for the shell script and its child scripts, so I did not have the luxury of running `env var=val cmd...`. As for `env` not being capable of modifying the shell's state, I think the difference is that, for me, it was modifying the shell script's state. Here's an example with two scripts: `/tmp/sleeper` (`date; sleep 1;`) and `/tmp/agent` (`/tmp/sleeper; env SHELLOPTS=xtrace; export SHELLOPTS; set -x; /tmp/sleeper;`) -- run `/tmp/agent`.

Comment: @JoeCasadonte, in your example above, the `env` command isn't doing any of the work; `set -x` changes SHELLOPTS in addition to changing the shell's local state, and `export SHELLOPTS` tells the shell to copy SHELLOPTS to the environment. Those are the only two moving parts that do anything important.

Comment: @JoeCasadonte, ...that said, I _did_ learn something here -- thank you!

Comment: As did I (and I've learned more from your posts over the last decade than you will ever know), so thank you, too!